# How to to insmod a module build with linux-headers-generic?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I have been trying to make a kernel module, but have run into problems due to the non-standard kernel I am using. I cannot find the headers using repositories, and have not yet been able to get help from the provider of the board I am using. Asking for help on here led to various advice, mainly that I probably don't know enough to fix this on my own. So I am looking for an alternate workaround.

I notice there is a package called 'linux-headers-generic', and was wondering if I could use that to make a module instead, since I don't have a matching version?

Trying to build a very basic module gives me the ERROR that it is an Invalid module format. Is there something I can include in either the makefile or module source that will allow the compiled .ko to be insertable?

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Its a Ubuntu based thing, but its custom from the makers of a component I am using.

Comment: Normally, vendors who distribute Linux must provide the source code, the source code includes the headers, of course. So, you would have to read the docs, go to their site to find out where to download the sources.